# How to chose right lens for concentrating IR signal?

Tags: optics, lenses, light-emitting-diodes

I am looking for the right acrylic lens. Since will be buying at least 1000 pieces I don't want to make any mistake.

I want to concentrate the signal from IR LED in a 1cm diameter tube at one point 20cm in diameter. From what I know, IR LEDs disperse the beam too widely, hence the need for a lens. What shape of lens should I buy? Are there any online resources that could help me

Wall is 5-10m away and LED wavelength is 970nm.

[image: 1]

Comment: How far is the tube from the wall?

Comment: 5-10m mostly 7m

Comment: What is the wavelength?

Comment: 970nm, please check edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convex lens can act to magnify the image of the LED onto the wall - which is what you want to do. The magnification depends on the distance of the lens to the wall and the focal length of the lens.

There are several things to consider in this:

1. What fraction of the light from the LED are you trying to collect: this helps determine how large the lens should be (diameter)
2. Does the LED already have a lens on it (it seems that it does) - if so what does that mean for the optical path

I would highly recommend that you experiment with a visible light LED first - you will find that at a certain distance the light from the LED is already "focused" - but exactly how it will be focused depends on the construction of the LED (often the LED is specified with a "view angle" which will tell you if the light is being concentrated into a narrow cone or a wide one. It makes a huge difference in answering this question). It is actually possible to get an "image" of the silicon die at the heart of a red LED (with clear lens) on a piece of paper for certain LEDs - basically almost exactly what you are asking for.

If we ignore the lens on the front of the LED for a moment (let's assume you have a bare die), then if the light emitting area is 1 mm^2 and you want to make it 20 cm in diameter, you need a 200x magnification.

In general, magnification is given by the ratio of distances on either side of the lens - if you are 1 m from the screen with your lens, then you would need the LED to be 5 mm from the lens since

$$M = \frac{d_{screen}}{d_{LED}}\\
d_{LED}=\frac{d_{screen}}{M}$$

Then you compute the focal length of the lens you need as

$$\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{d_{LED}} + \frac{1}{d_{screen}}$$

or

$$f_{lens}=\frac{d_{screen}}{M+1}$$
meaning that the focal length would be just a tiny bit less than 5 mm. If you get this even slightly wrong, then the object will either be out of focus, or the magnification will be significantly off. I suspect you can cope with the former better than the latter.

If you can assume your LED-with-built-in-lens behaves like a 6.35 mm diameter uniform disk, then the magnification you need is less - about 30x. In that case, for a screen distance of 1 m you need the LED at 33 mm and the focal length of the lens needs to be about 32 mm.

It doesn't really matter for this application whether the lens is plano-convex, or biconvex; I would recommend plano-convex, with the curved surface towards the LED. That is probably the cheapest solution.

But buy just one, and make an adjustable setup. Use a web camera to "see" the IR light from the LED, and play with the settings until you get it right.

Buying 1000 of the wrong thing is not fun - but it's not possible with the information given to give you an authoritative answer on the best solution.

Happy experimenting!

**UPDATE**

Since you have now specified the distance to the wall, you will probably have to stop down the aperture of the LED in order to get a sufficiently small spot - and in the process, lose a lot of the light output.

The key concept here is that when a light source is of a finite size, you can only focus it into a certain size spot at a certain distance. 7 m distance and 20 cm spot means that the angle subtended by the spot at the lens is only 1.6°. This in turn means that the LED must subtend the same angle at the lens - so if the LED is 1 mm in diameter, it has to be 35 mm away (namely $7000 * \frac{1}{200}$). If your LED already has a built in lens and an apparent aperture of 6 mm (the typical diameter of a LED with a lens) then you would need your second lens to be 6x35 = 210 mm away. If your LED's built in lens has a focusing angle of 8° (which is a fairly typical value), and you're trying to get down to 1.6°, you cut the angle by a factor 5x, and the area (fraction of power) by 25x. That's a big power loss...

Without knowing what exactly you are trying to achieve I don't know what to recommend - except "think more about what you are trying to achieve". To project a small spot at a long distance you need a well collimated source - and unless it starts out awfully small, you can only collimate by reducing intensity. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Let me emphasize two important points made above: 1. LEDs come with all sorts of lensing arrangements.  2. Buy one and figure out how to do it before buying 1000.   There's no way to guarantee that you can get this right without trying it out.  (Finding a solution with a *red* LED won't help.  Your IR LED will be different.)

Comment: A red LED is cheap and teaches you principles. The actual setup can only be achieved with the actual LED. Find one with a two degree half angle and quite possibly you simply need to set it up at the right distance... For an 8 degree LED see http://www.photonicsonline.com/doc/870nm-narrow-angle-emitters-0001

Comment: Thank you for such great answer, I am going to experiment ;).

Answer (score 1):

The lens should be convex. The die in the IR diode should be at the focal point of the lens. You will still need to be able to adjust its position to check. [This is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOorsuFF3X0) of someone doing something similar, but on a slightly larger scale. It would also be worth getting a webcam that respons to IR light so you can check illumination patterns

Comment: Any idea how to calculate it a little bit before I purchase one? To know how wide should it be in the middle and how in the edges etc? Anyway thank you! :)

Comment: And should it be double convex or only 1 convex? I guess 1 sided convex, since you didn't say double...